# C++: Reading Binary Files

Tags: c++

I have a Binary file that has several names followed by some details (50 bytes fixed). Each name is followed by 0X00 followed by the 50 byte details. I need to extract just the names from the file. i.e read all characters till 0x00, skip 50 bytes and continue till end of file.What is the best way to do it in C++.

Comment: This sounds very much like *give me teh codez* to me. There is a large number of question here on SO dealing with reading binary files in C++. There is more on other sites. And then there are books.

Comment: 1) Use a question mark if you're asking a question. 2) If you're not asking a question, don't post. 3) Show us what you've done so far and where your problem lies.

Comment: No, API would help. I have done only text files using >> operator.

Comment: maybe post a sketch of your existing code to give a feeling of what you are doing

Comment: If @Naszta's interpretation is right, I'd recommend using something like boost serialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

...
std::ifstream file("filename");
if ( ! file.is_open() )
  return;

std::string name;
char data[50];

while ( std::getline( file, name, '\0' ) && file.read( data, 50 ) )
{
  // you could use name and data
}
file.close();
...
```

Comment: @Naszta: I see; I think you might have found the correct interpretation of the question. Let's see what the OP says (IYAM: what is the point of stressing '_fixed size_' records, when the interleaving strings arent)

Comment: @sehe: I just answer the question. If I had to store some structure, I would store it in XML. :)

Comment: In other hand: many times we should read stupid formats, because our partner force some stupid thing. So to read stupid formats are okay for me, because many time there is no option to do it better.

Comment: @Naszta: Me too. Although, what we both have done first is _interpret_ the question :) That's why I was inadvertently found defending my interpretation. I meant nothing against yours

Comment: @Mike Seymour This is what I have been looking for and asking. Didn't know there is something like `getline(file, name, '\0')`! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the 'learn a man to fish' department: [www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/read/)

Simplistic approach:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>   

int main()
{
    char buf[50];
    std::ifstream ifs("data.bin", std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::in);
    while (ifs.read(buf, sizeof(buf)))
    {
        if (!ifs.eof())
        {
            std::cout << std::string(buf) << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;
    ifs.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How to read the string till the 0x00 byte. Should I read each byte and then check for 0x00 and form string?

Comment: @Xia: i do recommend you to try this first. Obviously you are spectacularly missing the point about C-strings being null-terminated. [The conversion to `std::string` implicitly read _up to the first null char_](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/). [TYVM] off-the-wall: _(to think I felt silly writing the explicit conversion to std::string in the first place)_